# Debian on Mac via rEFInd: New Partitions Don't Boot

Tags: debian, uefi, boot-loader, macintosh, refind

I am trying to get on Debian via the refind Bootmanager. I was able to create partitions on HDD (Swap + /) and install Debian, but I couldn't install a bootloader on the installation, nor Grub neither LILO, and now the partitions don't start. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing reFINd with the following command?

```
./install.sh --alldrivers
```

I actually had installed reFINd withouth this option at first, and I could not boot my Debian. Then I reinstalled it like this, and reFINd detected it in the next reboot.